# Plotting polygon on map with length of sides known and lat lng known only for two vertices and no angles known

Tags: polygon, google-maps, latitude-longitude, angles, calculate-geometry

I have an image(a polygon), generated by survey department from a field survey. I know the lat lng of two vertices and the length of all sides.I do not know the size of the angles.(Using a protractor on a printed image  may help i guess. Not sure).

I want to use this details to plot the same in a map(for ex. google map). I want to know how to find the lat lng of other vertices.

Comment: How many vertices are you trying to interpolate? If you know two points (A and B) and the distance from both you can use two circle intersection https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Circle-CircleIntersection.html resulting in two points (C and D) then find the intersection of lines AB and CD, if your survey is accurate enough the line CD may be nearly 0 length. If you don't know both ends or are trying to interpolate more than 1 vertex I don't think that can be done.

Comment: Some have 4 vertices. Others will have upto 7.